# Howto: Install Imagick (for php) on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: php, imagick, pecl

I'm attempting to install ImagicK as its required for a Yii Extension I want to use for my project.

I've checked around and followed a few different suggestions but nothing that has worked so far, ultimately the framework extension is still throwing me an error (Must have ImagicK installed).

I've tried things like:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install imagick-php5 .. etc
```

as well as the PECL install which ends up throwing me the following error:

```
Checking ImageMagick MagickWand API configuration program... configure: error: 
not found. Please provide a path to MagickWand-config or Wand-config program.
```

Any help as to how to get ImagicK installed and integrated with PHP on Ubuntu 11.10 would be great.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

The package has a different name in Ubuntu.

```
 sudo apt-get install php5-imagick
```

The error with building via PECL means you must install `libmagickwand-dev, libmagickcore3, libmagickwand3` probably (there are alternatives: `graphicsmagick-imagemagick-compat`, see Synaptic).

Comment: Not usally. You may wish to check `/etc/php5/conf.d/`. But installing such a package ought to add an uncommented directive there.

Comment: Sorry, I was actually doing something else wrong, but thanks for the info!

Comment: `sudo apt-get install php5.6-imagick` now for Ubuntu 16.04 and upper

Comment: `sudo apt-get install imagemagick php-imagick` for Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 60):

Installation steps for Ubuntu 12.04:

1. **Install imagemagick**

   > sudo apt-get install imagemagick
2. **Install imagemagick PECL extension**

   > sudo apt-get install php5-imagick
3. **Restart webserver**

Comment: Thumbs up for not assuming I already had imagemagick installed.

Comment: you should also mention that a webserver restart seems to be required

Comment: In my case I had to do `sudo service nginx restart` and `sudo service php5-fpm restart`.

Comment: If you are using php 5.6, then you need to do `sudo apt-get install php5.6-imagick`. And for nginx and php-fpm: `sudo service nginx restart` and `sudo service php5.6-fpm restart`

Answer (score 12):

Installation steps for Ubuntu < 16.04:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick php5-imagick; sudo service apache2 restart
```

Installation steps for Ubuntu > 16.04:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick php-imagick; sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: You wrote the same thing twice.

Comment: Actually, they are different. Notice that one has `php5-imagick` and the other `php-imagick`

Answer (score 2):

For Ubuntu 16 or later:

```
sudo apt-get install php-imagick
```

(note the use of `php-` instead of `php5-`)

Answer (score 1):

Install imagemagick with :

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

Install imagemagick PECL extension :

```
sudo apt-get install php5-imagick
```

Restart webserver

Answer (score 1):

For php8 this is all you need:

```
apt-get install -y php8.0-imagick
```

Answer (score 0):

With Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial) with PHP 5.6 not 7. PHP 7 was disabled.

1. sudo apt-get update
2. sudo apt-get install imagemagick php5.6-imagick