# Adding php extension to a shared server

Tags: php, linux, web-hosting, imagick, php-extension

I'm trying to upload my script on a commercial server. But its `fail to load class imagick`.

I have installed imagick on my home computer and copied the imagick.so file to the server and added a new `php.ini`. It contents are

```
extension=imagick.so
```

but it doesn't work.

What do you think I should do?

Comment: Find a host that supports imagemagick

Comment: You can't add extensions like you do. Follow @JohnConde's advice.

Comment: i already paid for this. and it's not an option.

Comment: Then contact your host that you want Imagemagick support, perhaps they're willing to add this.

Comment: maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870878/howto-install-imagick-for-php-on-ubuntu-11-10) helps?

Comment: http://adrian.hopebailie.com/2007/07/php5-extensions-shared-server/